# How to determine sequence no for pre-authorised transaction with time bound validity without blocking other new possible transactions

Tags: transactions, sequence-number, smart-contract

If a pre-authorised transaction is created for time bound validity after 50 days and submitted to the network, does this mean another transaction before 50 days cannot happen as the sequence number would be greater than the pre-authorised one?

Answer (score 3):

The pre-signed transaction will be invalidated if someone submits a transaction against the same account. This is possible because the account is not `locked` and therefore someone with the secret key is able to submit transactions against the account.

Any new transaction submitted against the account would increase the `sequence_number` on the account which would make the `sequence_number` used in the pre-signed transaction invalid, effectively invalidating the whole pre-signed transaction.

---

[Pre-signed transactions](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/multi-sig.html#pre-authorized-transaction) are special in that:

1. they are bound to a specific account
2. they are bound to a specific sequence number
3. they are (optionally) bound to a specific time period
4. they are signed by a specific [signer](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/multi-sig.html#alternate-signature-types)

The account still functions like normal even if you have made public any pre-signed transactions. Therefore, the best approach when working with pre-signed transactions is to create a separate **escrow** account that is **locked**, [only allowing your pre-authorized transaction to execute](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/multi-sig.html#pre-authorized-transaction).

---

Here are the steps to create `pre-authorized` transactions on the Stellar network using an **escrow** account that is **locked**:

1. Create a new account. **This is the `escrow` account**.
2. Fund it with the assets that you need (including the minimum account reserves and the expected transaction fees).
3. Assuming the `sequence_number` on the `escrow` account is currently `100`, create a time-locked transaction with the `sequence_number=102` (yes, we intentionally skipped `101`, we are saving it up for *step 6*). **This is the `pre-authorized` transaction that you will distribute**.

   *Note that this transaction is **not signed** and should not be submitted to the network yet*.
4. Create a second time-locked transaction with the same `sequence_number=102`. The *startTime* should be after the *maxTime* of your `pre-authorized` transaction (say, 1 day). **This is your `abort` transaction**.

   *Note that this transaction is **not signed** and should only be submitted to the network to recover the funds in the case that your `pre-authorized` transaction is never submitted (which is why it shares the same `sequence_number`)*.
5. Create a third time-locked transaction with the `sequence_number=103`. The *startTime* should be after the *startTime* of your `abort` transaction (say, 1 day). **This is your `merge` transaction**.

   *Note that this transaction is **not signed** and should only be submitted to the network after either the `pre-authorized` transaction or the `abort` transaction is submitted so the `sequence_number` on the account is at `102` before this transaction is submitted. This transaction allows you to recover the min-reserve on the account by merging the `escrow` account into your original account using the [Merge Account](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#account-merge) operation*.
6. Now that we have our 3 transactions (`pre-authorized`, `abort`, and `merge`) we need to set the correct signers on the `escrow` account to allow these transactions to function as expected. You will need to create a transaction with `sequence_number=101` (this is where we use the saved up sequence number). This transaction should have the following operations and **should be submitted to the network**:

   a. add the hash of the `pre-authorized` transaction as a signer

   b. add the hash of the `abort` transaction as a signer

   c. add the hash of the `merge` transaction as a signer

   d. sets the **master-key weight** to `0`. *This is very important to **lock** the account and must be the last operation in this transaction*.
7. You will end up with an `escrow` account that is `locked` which only allows 2 of the 3 transactions to be executed. **You should *distribute* the `pre-authorized` transaction to the concerned party and keep the `abort` and `merge` transactions with you**.

   *Note that these transactions can **only** be submitted in the order of `pre-authorized` followed by `merge` **OR** `abort` followed by `merge`. If they are submitted in any other order they will not have any effect and **will not bump the `sequence_number`**.*

This is now a **[Stellar Smart Contract](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/walkthroughs/stellar-smart-contracts.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, but keep in mind that pre-authorized transactions are not valid until a matching transaction is sent. That means that you could create a new transaction with the same sequence number as that of the pre-authorized transaction and send it to the network.

The network will accept this new transaction, and when the 50 days are due and you send the pre-authorized transaction the network will reject it (because the sequence number has been used).

A safer approach might be to create a separate account for all these pre-authorized transactions